# How To Get the Small Sized MFC Source Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, build, mfc

i have made an MFC application.
i want to send it via Email,but the size of the source code after build is very big.
i want to get only the necessary files to send via Email, and let the receiver build the solution on his computer.

what should i put inside the folder that i'll send ?

Comment: I'm confused.  Building your source code will **not** increase its size.  It will produce intermediate objects and executable files.  What are you trying to send?  Hopefully, only .cpp and .h files.

Comment: yes only cpp and h files but the project folder is huge ... and this only happens after i build the solution for first time

Comment: What is the largest file in the folder and what is its file extension?

Comment: my solution name is SlnFilter
my project name is ProFilter

SlnFilter.sdf =83.3 mbs
Debug folder = 10 mbs
ProFilter\Debug =48 mbs
ipch folder= 86.8 mbs

Comment: You want to email only. Cpp, .h, .sln and. Vcxproj.  Collect those file types using a zip program and send them.

Comment: i did that exactly but when i tried opening the solution file it gave me error saying that it could't locate the "ProFilter.vcxproj" although its there and in the same directory

Comment: You should absolutely start to use a version control system, e.g. SVN. Sending e-mails to each other is just not a good way to work together on the same code, not even for small projects.

Comment: i've solved it .. i made the folders with the same name and structure of my original solution and put "ProFilter.vcxproj.user" in the solution folder ... when i double clicked the slnFilter.sln file the solution and the project loaded successfully

Comment: As the file extension implies, the .user file is user specific. Do not include it when exchanging source code. The .filter file - if present - should be included.

Answer (score -1):

You can omit the \Debug and \Release directories.

Comment: idid exactly that but when i tried building the project again it gave me error saying that it could't  locate the "ProFilter.vcxproj" although its there and in the same directory

Comment: That's not going to do a whole lot. Don't forget about the .user file, .suo, .sdf and .opensdf (the latter two are fairly large). Plus failing to mention other platforms (notably x64) disqualifies this as an answer.